# How can you import Wireless Network (WiFi) passwords / settings to Mac OSX 10.10 from a text, html or xml file?

Tags: network, wifi, password, keychain, import

I'm trying to transfer WiFi settings of saved networks from a Windows PC to a Macbook.

I have exported the wireless settings via the freeware WirelessKeyView to a txt file (can also be created as a html or xml file).

Is it possible to import these settings to the Macbook so that it saves the wireless network names and passwords?

I have no knowledge of coding and I'm totally new to Mac. However I'm eager to learn.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/950383/584424) and see if it helps.  It doesn't look like it will be easy unless someone has written a tool for it.

Comment: @Raystafarian suggested to type in the following in the Terminal app:
networksetup -addpreferredwirelessnetworkatindex $device_name $SSID $Index $Security_type $Password

What do these 3 correspond to?:
$device_name 
$SSID 
$Index 

E.g. I have the following info for a wireless network:
Netowrk name:abc 
Connection Type:ESS 
Authentication:WPA2PSK 
Encryption:AES 
Password:12345678

Also, can several networks be imported simultaneously via this method?

Comment: @fbara thanks it worked! Just need a script to read the txt file and parse it to the above mentioned command.

Comment: @Raystafarian thanks for your solution. Going to search for that script you mentioned in your answer [http://superuser.com/a/950383/584424]